# in sql how to return single row of data from more than one row in the same table

Tags: sql, ms-access, self-join

I have a single table of activities, some labelled 'Assessment' (type_id of 50) and some 'Counselling' (type_id of 9) with dates of the activities. I need to compare these dates to find how long people wait for counselling after assessment.  The table contains rows for many people, and that is the primary key of 'id'.  My problem is how to produce a result row with both the assessment details and the counselling details for the same person, so that I can compare the dates.  I've tried joining the table to itself, and tried nested subqueries, I just can't fathom it.  I'm using Access 2010 btw.
Please forgive my stupidity, but here's an example of joining the table to itself that doesn't work, producing nothing (not surprising):

Table looks like:

```
ID    TYPE_ID   ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME
----------------------------------
1        9      20130411  
1     v 50 v    20130511  
2        9      20130511  
3        9      20130511
```

In the above the last two rows have only had assessment so I want to ignore them, and just work on the situation where there's both assessment and counselling 'type-id'

```
SELECT
  civicrm_activity.id, civicrm_activity.type_id,
  civicrm_activity.activity_date_time,
  civicrm_activity_1.type_id,
  civicrm_activity_1.activity_date_time
FROM
  civicrm_activity INNER JOIN civicrm_activity AS civicrm_activity_1
  ON civicrm_activity.id = civicrm_activity_1.id
WHERE
  civicrm_activity.type_id=9
  AND civicrm_activity_1.type_id=50;
```

I'm actually wondering whether this is in fact not possible to do with SQL?  I hope it is possible?  Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Your query looks spot on to me. What happens when you run it?

Comment: could you show the results without the where clause?

Comment: I've now spent a little time setting this up, and have run your query and it **still** seems spot on to me. It returned the row for person 1 with the dates of assessment and counselling. If it's not behaving the way you expect, then perhaps you've made a mistake setting up the tables. I also wonder about your comment `The table contains rows for many people, and that is the primary key of 'id'` - since your example has two rows with id 1, it can't be a primary key - just flailing around here, trying to work out what problem you're encountering.

Comment: Perhaps I should say that I've got this working on www.sqlfiddle.com using SQL Server 2008. Maybe it's some kind of limitation on MS Access?

Comment: HIPAA-compliance demands a more secure database than MS-Access when working with personal health information. I hope you don't have patient-names or other PHI in that database :-)

Comment: Are you getting the set of patient assessment rows, by patient, and then inner joining the set of patient counseling rows that occurred *after* the patient's assessment date? You need a date-time condition on the join if you want to calculate the time between assessment and counseling on a patient-by-patient basis.

Comment: Also, if a patient can have multiple counseling sessions following assessement, you need to find the min() post-assessment counseling date for that patient-assessment if you want to know how long it takes for counseling to start, post assessment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you only want to get the ID numbers where you have a TYPE_ID entry of both 9 and 50.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM civicrm_activity WHERE type_id = '9' AND id IN (SELECT id FROM civicrm_activity WHERE type_id = '50');
```

This will give you a list of id's that has entries with both type_id 9 and 50. With that list you can now go and get the specifics.

**Use this SQL for the time of type_id 9**

```
SELECT activity_date_time FROM civicrm_activity WHERE id = 'id_from_last_sql' AND type_id = '9'
```

**Use this SQL for the time of type_id 50**

```
SELECT activity_date_time FROM civicrm_activity WHERE id = 'id_from_last_sql' AND type_id = '50'
```

Comment: Surely, the OP's `WHERE civicrm_activity.type_id=9 AND civicrm_activity_1.type_id=50` will restrict the rows his query returns to id's with both type_id 9 and 50?

Comment: That's true nurdglaw - it returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks OK to me, too.  The one problem might be that you use only one table alias.  I don't know, but perhaps Access treats the table name "specially" such that, in effect, the WHERE clause says

```
WHERE
    civicrm_activity.type_id=9
AND civicrm_activity.type_id=50;
```

That would certainly explain zero rows returned!

To fix that, use an alias for each table.  I suggest shorter ones,

```
SELECT  A.id, A.type_id, A.activity_date_time,
              B.type_id, B.activity_date_time
FROM  civicrm_activity as A 
JOIN  civicrm_activity as B
ON    A.id = B.id
WHERE A.type_id=9
AND   B.type_id=50;
```